# How to divide all rows in colum by specific rowname in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a `df` like this:

```
         COL1      COL2
AA       1122.7    1212
AB       2334.4    3121
AC       3235.0    975
BC       2231.6    520
BD       6456.0    4005
CC       3225.4    9986
min      234.3     60
```

How can I divide all column values by the value of `"min"` row?

I'm trying something like this

```
df[,] <- lapply(df[,], function(x) x/x[["min"]])
```

But I receive `Subscript out of bounds`

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this can help:

```
#Code
newdf <- df1/apply(df1,2,min)
```

Output:

```
        COL1      COL2
AA   4.79172 20.200000
AB  38.90667 13.320529
AC  13.80708 16.250000
BC  37.19333  2.219377
BD  27.55442 66.750000
CC  53.75667 42.620572
min  1.00000  1.000000
```

Or this:

```
#Index
v <- rownames(df1)
i <- which(v=='min')
#Code 2
newdf <- df1[-i,]/df1[i,,drop=T]
newdf <- rbind(newdf,df1[i,])
```

Output:

```
          COL1       COL2
AA    4.791720  20.200000
AB    9.963295  52.016667
AC   13.807085  16.250000
BC    9.524541   8.666667
BD   27.554417  66.750000
CC   13.766112 166.433333
min 234.300000  60.000000
```

Comment: "min" is a rowname, not necesary the min value of the row. If I do this, i receive a NA `df`

Comment: @Aw3same I noticed that, I added a new update. Please check if that works and sorry!

Comment: @Aw3same Fantastic! And sorry for misunderstanding your issue! Greetings!

Answer (score 0):

We need `sapply` instead of `lapply` as `lapply` returns a `list` by default, while `sapply` returns a `vector` when there is a single value

```
newdf <- df1/sapply(df1, min)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try sapply, sapply() function does the same job as lapply() function but returns a vector

df/sapply(df,min)